# How to modify local contrast in Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, post-processing

How to modify local contrast of a photo in Lightroom 4? The only thing comes into my mind is to use the brush tool. Is there any other way to achieve this or a plug-in to let me modify the local contrast of part of the image?

Comment: Please note that "local contrast" usually means contrast on small spatial scales (e.g. edges), not "contrast in a particular region of the image". Clarity is basically a "local contrast" tool.  The adjustment brush can be used to adjust contrast in a region. Examples of local contrast: http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/local-contrast-enhancement.htm

Comment: The brush tool does exactly what you're after. Could you explain more clearly why you want to avoid using it? Using a plug-in to do something LR already does natively seems completely unnecessary to me.

Comment: @MarkWhitaker Usually software will apply algorithms to adjust contrast locally not globally. Although the image may look unrealistic, I just have the curiosity to try it out. I do use the brush to edit contrast in some areas in the image but I wanted to try something else.

Comment: I'm still not clear on WHY you want to try something else? Can you give details of a situation where you feel Lightroom isn't delivering what you need? I'm not trying to argue with you, just helping clarify your question so you get more useful answers.

Comment: Put another way: my recommendation would always be to use the local adjustment brush in Lightroom. Without clearer information in your question I can't understand why that's not the answer you want.

Comment: @MarkWhitaker sometimes the results doesn't please me when I use native lightroom tools. For example I used black/white adjustments in lightroom but when I used Niksoftware I found it easier, faster and with better results

Comment: Still not clear what your specific problem is with *local contrast adjustments*. So my answer is: use the local adjustments brush in Lightroom. It's versatile, powerful and convenient!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a Lightroom user (often), so I'm not overly familiar with what's available natively, but you might find a plug-in like [Topaz Adjust 5](http://www.topazlabs.com/adjust/) to be just about the right size and shape of ticket. It works from within both Lightroom and Photoshop (and any PS plug-in compatible editor, as well as a standalone with a free lightweight host), and offers both global and local adjustments. The ability to paint effects in and out is, I think, a deliberate nod to the environments that won't allow you to play with layers in the host program.

(No affiliation—I'm even deliberately avoiding the affiliate program—just a very satisfied user.)

Comment: +1 like the tool. Looks like it does more than local contrast adjusting. Thanks

Comment: Why use a third-party program from LR, which will require you to create a copy of the image, when LR lets you do it all in one place using the original file?

Comment: @MarkWhitaker - hmmm... perhaps because the third-party program will let you do things that Lightroom alone cannot?

Comment: Another tool that does a fantastic job is the Tonal Contrast filter in Nik's Color Efex bundle.  An expensive plugin, but allows you to separately adjust contrast in shadow, mid-tones and highlights, and also apply local changes using "control points".

Answer (score 1):

> Clarity Adds depth to an image by increasing local contrast

From [Adobe's site](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Lightroom/2.0/WS39A2F4C6-3758-4176-9D6D-B26477EC2C71.html).

Comment: I *think* the question concerns the local adjustment of contrast, not "local contrast" as the term is used in a technical sense. I tried to get clarification with my comment above, but I'm still unclear as to the goal and the shortcomings of the built-in tools.